# ModuleNotFound error Django and Heroku deployment

Tags: django, heroku

I am new to Django and to programming overall, and I am trying to deploy my personal website developed with Django to heroku.

I feel like I am at the last step but one error keeps bugging me and I cannot solve it on my own or with documentation.

My project folders are like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZc34.png)

My Procfile: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhnEI.png)

My wsgi file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSHEL.png)

And in the heroku logs I get the following:

```
2020-01-04T15:45:47.211072+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blog'
```

There are many blue lines but I believe this is the one that is problematic (i.e. not being able to find the settings file from this)

Is there anything else I can provide if this is not clear?

Thanks for any help

I welcome any questions

**UPDATE!**

So, I updated the db I use from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL and I still get a Server Error 500.

Here is my manage.py where I put the PostgreSQL:

[DATABASE in manage.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsaRh.png)

The app runs when I do `manage.py runserver` but it does not when heroku deploys it.

The heroku log looks like this:

[heroku log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnV2g.png)

Comment: Hey Ivan. At first, try to modify your Procfile: replace `web: gunicorn mysite.mysite.wsgi` with `web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi`

Comment: I get ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.wsgi'```. That is because my procfile is two folders out and now it is trying to find a wsgi in the first mysite folder but there is not one, it is in mysite -> mysite -> wsgi

Comment: Oh, no... I haven't noticed the application is inside mysite. If you move the root mysite folder content into icc-blog then everything will work fine.

Comment: this is the main folder for the python project, cannot move it that easily. Also I tried to move the Procfile to mysite directory, and when heroku starts building, it does not run the procfile for some reason

Comment: Do you run development web server like `python manage.py runserver`? If like this, that the running directory is not the same as for gunicorn. The most convenient way is to run both webservers from the same folder. But theres --chdir argument for gunicorn which can help you to solve the issue.

Comment: I can run manage.py runserver. the blog folder is one of Django's ready to use packages and the mysite points to it for resources. Can I share my screen on discord or something ? or I can give you more pictures

Comment: Please try to modify the Procfile as follows: `web: gunicorn --pythonpath mysite mysite.wsgi` Finally it has to work.

Comment: is pythonpath supposed to be the path/to/python and also is there supposed to be empty space between mysite and mysite.wsgi ?

Comment: Yep, just copy-paste this line as is with an empty space.

Comment: ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.mysite'```. The line is the same as you gave it ```web: gunicorn --pythonpath mysite mysite.wsgi
```

Comment: Okay, i'm gonna reproduce your case by myself in my heroku account. Wait a bit please.

Comment: so this error was because I had mysite.mysite.settings in wsgi, but now I put it to mysite.settings, the logs are clear, but in the website I get a server error 500

Comment: I reproduced the project by myself with no errors. It's nice Procfile issue has gone. Are the logs completely empty or you have no stacktrace there?

Comment: ```2020-01-04T17:09:23.269715+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.38.252.121 - - [04/Jan/2020:17:09:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36"
2020-01-04T17:09:23.271960+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=ivan-ivanov.herokuapp.com request_id=9cdfba9e-3b90-40e1-9c68-81523f68e663 fwd="37.143.243.254" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=138ms status=500 bytes=380 protocol=https``` this is what I get when I use the link provided by heroku

Comment: do you think I need to do something to the database ?

Comment: You have sqlite but it is not supported by heroku. Set up postgresql according to heroku documentation and everything will work fine.

Comment: @artembo hey, can you look at the update I provided

Comment: Pls add release phase to Procfile: ‘release: cd mysite && python manage.py migrate’ Or you can ‘Heroku run bash’ and do it manually. Sorry, I’m available on smartphone only, could help you tomorrow only.

Comment: @artembo how can I reference you. You have been SUPER helpful. Do you have a personal website or something I can put as a name, because I write daily blog posts and I want to thank you there

Comment: or maybe write all your comments as an aswer and I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarise the process of investigating startup problems. There were two issues:

**1.** The project layout was different for local development and for production on heroku whereas the codebase was set up for highest level *mysite* as a homepath except *wsgi.py* file what caused spending extra time on troubleshooting.

```
.
├── Procfile <- web: gunicorn mysite.mysite.wsgi
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── blog
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── manage.py <- python manage.py runserver
│   ├── mysite
│   ├── static
│   ├── staticfiles
│   └── templates
├── requirements.txt
└── venv
```

**Solution**:

Fix codebase for *mysite* as a homepath and run gunicorn with either *--chdir* or *--pythonpath* setting to have a proper path settings for *gunicorn*.

*--chdir*: Chdir to specified directory before apps loading:

```
web: gunicorn --chdir mysite mysite.wsgi
```

*--pythonpath*: Add directories to the Python path

```
web: gunicorn --pythonpath mysite mysite.wsgi
```

**2.** Migrations. There wasn't any migration applying action.

**Solution**:

Adding *release* phase to Procfile which will apply migrations every time the app is deployed:

```
release: cd mysite && python manage.py migrate
```

After solving these two issues the app got up and running.

Comment: can you help look into this similar question please? Ive been stucked on this for days without any headway.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63465541/django-vuejs-app-deployed-to-heroku-showing-application-error-on-page?noredirect=1#comment112420587_63465541